# How to detect new day has goned in runtime?

Tags: php, logic, runtime, days

How to detect current day has end, and new day has goned in php runtime (detection function or logic, etc.)?

```
while(true) {
    if (hasNewDayGoned()) {
        // on new day work...
    }
    
    // normal work...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is an infinite loop for a script you keep running continuously.

In that case you can just check the date against the last run.

For example

```php
$old_day = 0;
while (true) {
    if (date("Ymd") > $old_day) {
        // on new day work...
        $old_day = date("Ymd");
    }
    // normal work...
}
```

Depending on if you want your code the first time you start the script, you can set the initial `$old_day` either to `0` or `date("Ymd")`

EDIT:
Forgot to add that if your server is in a different timezone, you can use `date_default_timezone_set` as [documented here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: No problem! If this helped and solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted for future readers.